# Failed to connect apple push notification gateway

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

i tested my server with telnet, it seems like working fine:

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.142...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

but i try to run sample_push.php file in PHP-APNS , but it show error below:

```
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:13 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:13 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:13 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Retry to connect (1/3)...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:14 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:14 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:14 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Retry to connect (2/3)...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:15 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:15 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195':  (0)
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:15 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Retry to connect (3/3)...
Sat, 30 Apr 2011 18:21:16 +0800 ApnsPHP[14447]: INFO: Trying ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ApnsPHP_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'.................
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you provide a wrong certificate, Apple will disconnect your TLS connection.

So you can telnet the APNS port, but fail to connect.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.x now. I disable the Verification of peer. I still found the same problem on connection to Apple Push server. Any hint on how to generate the required .pem for Sandbox and Production on Ubuntu ?

Comment: In KeyChain Access, select the certificate and choose File > Export Items. Select the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) option, select a save location, and click Save.

    Launch the Terminal application and enter the following command after the prompt:

    openssl pkcs12 -in CertificateName.p12 -out CertificateName.pem -nodes


http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Comment: If it's certificate problem, you can see status of connection to APNS become time_wait when you specify you certificate(debug it)